# How to solve gradle build problem in React Native Expo?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, gradle

My app is working fine when i run it on Expo Go. Any time I try to build I got Build error below:

```
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.

Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build

[stderr] 

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

[stderr] 

* Where:

[stderr] 

Script '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle' line: 426

[stderr] 

* What went wrong:

[stderr] 

A problem occurred evaluating script.

[stderr] 

>

[stderr] 

Calling `[node, /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/bin.js, config]` finished with an exception. Error message: groovy.json.JsonException: Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object

[stderr] 

  

[stderr] 

  The current character read is 'i' with an int value of 105

[stderr] 

Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
```

I always run eas build -p android --profile preview

developmentClient is set to true under development.

How can I fix this issue.